# Firebase Realtime Database Only Retrieving data with User's ID

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need help guys. I am trying to retrieve data from firebase database only inserted by user. I managed to make the user send his ID with his data, and now I am trying to get his data only.

this is the code

```
 public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        homeViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        mUploads = new ArrayList<>();


        mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        final String id = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        final Upload u = new Upload();

        mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");

        //Query query = mDatabaseRef.child("").equalTo("-MUiNO146Q64ztT_kY9y");

     
        mDBListener = mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                mUploads.clear();
                Upload upload2 = dataSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);

                    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Upload upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                        //Toast.makeText(getContext(), id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            upload.setKey(postSnapshot.getKey());
                            mUploads.add(upload);

                    }







                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                mProgressCircle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mProgressCircle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });



        return root;
    }
```

this image shows the structure of the database

[image: structure of the database]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there with the commented out code.

What you're looking for is a query, which allows you to [order/filter data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data). In your case, you can get the uploads for the current user with:

```
if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null) {
  String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

  mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");
  Query query = mDatabaseRef.orderByChild("id").equalTo(uid);
 
  mDBListener = query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
      ...
```